# Calling random altered functions based on an original function

Tags: c++, function, random

Let's say that I have 10 altered functions for each original function, which all do the same, just different process of execution and maths. I want to call a random function out of the 10 altered functions instead of the original function every time the original function is supposed to be used in the code. How can I do that and avoid getting the 9 other altered functions compiled, that were not selected by random and won't be used?

This is to hand out a "different" build for each receiver with an unique signature. Only possible way of doing it, that I can think of, is to have a folder for each original function that holds 10 separate include files, for each altered function. This is kinda messy, but it's the only way that I can think of.

If there's an easier way of doing, what I want to achieve, please let me know. For example just adding junk code to the original function randomly on compiling - which would be even better, since it's dynamic. I just can't imagine of a way on how to do it.

Here's some pseudo: http://pastebin.com/v7Hv53nS

Comment: As there are no compile-time random numbers generation facilities, I guess the easiest way is to generate a random index in your Makefile, pass it to the compiler as a macro, and use it inside the source code to tag-dispatch into a set of overloaded functions.

Comment: Do you want the choice of implementation to be *random*, or do you want it to be *different for each signature*?

Comment: Different for each signature @Beta

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be divided into two smaller problems.

**Part 1:** Determine which variant to give to the receiver. This is equivalent to mapping signatures to `{1,...,10}` without collision. Incidentally, this means that there can be ten unique signatures at most. (If you do this with more than one function, then you must decide whether each receiver shall receive *a set of unique implementations* or a *unique set of implementations*, but never mind that for now.) This does not seem to be the part you're asking about, so let's suppose we put this logic into an executable (e.g. a script) called `pickVariant`.

**Part 2:** Given the choice of variant, compile the variant and construct the package (executable, library, whatever) for the receiver. I would do it this way:

In the Makefile:

```
VARIANT := $(shell pickVariant $(SIGNATURE))

foo.o: foo.cc
    @$(CXX) $< -DVARIANT=$(VARIANT) -c -Wall -o $@
```

In foo.cc:

```
int addTwo(int n)
{
  int res;
#if VARIANT==1
  res = n+2;
#elif VARIANT==2
  res = n+1+1;
#elif VARIANT==3
  res = 5+n-3;
...
#elif VARIANT==10
  res = 2*n+2-n;
#endif

  return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was trying to do! However, 1 question remains. What does the Makefile part actually do? I'm not using Makefile, but I'm assuming it has something to do with adding a line/function, which creates a random VARIANT value every compile? Is it possible to achieve without Makefile, so I can just hardcode it in my app? @Beta

Comment: @PriitJõe: Sorry, I was under the impression that you were using Make; what *are* you using? The core is the invocation of the compiler: `g++ foo.cc -DVARIANT=7 -c -o foo.o`, or something like that.

Comment: I'm running VS 2015 Pro and building a simple console app. I'm not that familiar with boost or any other bigger libraries for that matter, as well as cmake eco. Can I still do this somehow do this? @Beta

Comment: @PriitJõe: I'm sure VS can do it, but I'm not an expert on VS so I don't know exactly how. I'd check the documentation for "preprocessor macro".